# Получить название улицы и района

Tags: jquery, html5, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

У меня есть широта и долгота — как получить название улицы и района?

(данные получены с помощью html5 `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`)

Comment: Через апи гугла или яндекса можно. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В строке запроса к API замените <долгота> и <широта> на соответствующие значения.

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?&geocode=E<долгота>,N<широта>
```

В ответ получите xml, где в GeocoderMetaData указан адрес.

Например для 30.316785 и 59.926353, запрос такой

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?&geocode=E30.316785,N59.926353
```

В [ответ](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?&geocode=E30.316785,N59.926353) получим xml с адресом: Россия, Санкт-Петербург, Сенная площадь.

---

Описание параметров запроса к API - [тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/).

Получить значение <долгота> и <широта> можно на сайте https://maps.yandex.ru
Для этого выберите точку на карте, в контекстном меню надо выбрать "что здесь?" и в панели справа посмотрите значение долготы и широты.

Comment: К примеру, Санкт-Петербург метро садовая,узнал координаты,формирую строку запроса https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?&geocode=E%3C30.316785%3E,N%3C59.926353%3E  мне почему то выдает просто Россия,а дальше Украина,Луганск и тд,где я ошибся?

Comment: @zkolya `<` и `>` указывать не надо. добавил пример в ответ

Comment: Спасибо,очень помогли.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ, который дал @Stack, касается `yandex-maps-api`. Однако в метках у Вас указан также `google-maps-api`, поэтому позволю себе ответить про google.

Итак, принцип тот же самый, что и в Яндексе: в адресной строке (или используя `curl`) вызываете адрес

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=<широта>,<долгота>&language=ru
```

В ответе получим JSON объект с максимально доступными данными.
Для Вашего примера будет вот так:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=59.926353,30.316785&language=ru

И это дает адрес вплоть до номера дома. Конечно такая точность не всегда возможна...

Замечания:

- Если в вызываемой строке заменить `/json?` на `/xml?`, то возврат будет в `xml` формате.
- атрибут `language` не обязателен. Если его указать - ответ будет содержать названия по-русски. Если его не указывать - названия будут в основном по-английски